# Matplotlib dataframe pie chart plotting is overlapping my 0% labels

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This is my code and I have my visualization below. My issue is that when I try to plot my aggregated dataframe it keeps overlapping some of the slice labels and is making it look cluttered and unreadable.

```
style.use('fivethirtyeight')
age_df = fixed_df.groupby(['Intake Condition']).agg({'Animal 
ID':'count'})
age_df.plot.pie(figsize=(20,10), subplots=True,autopct='%1.000f%%')
plt.title("Conditions of Animals Brought In")
```

[image: Pie chart visualization of the above code]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to avoid overlapping of labels & autopct in a matplotlib pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577505/how-to-avoid-overlapping-of-labels-autopct-in-a-matplotlib-pie-chart)