# Avoiding overlapping when slices are tiny

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I would like to know I can I add callouts in a pie chart.
I have this dataset:

```
       ID   Colour
0   27995   red
1   36185   orange
2   57204   blue
3   46009   red
4   36241   white
5   63286   blue
6   68905   blue
7   3798    green
8   53861   yellow
...
199 193 brown
```

and when I try to generate a pie chart using pandas:

```
df.groupby(Colour).size().plot(kind='pie',figsize=(15,15), label="", labeldistance=0.8, autopct='%1.0f%%',  pctdistance=0.5,legend=True)
```

I get an awful chart where colours overlap since slices are very tiny and percentage values  overlap too.
I know that it could be easier to manage the chart as follows:

[How to avoid overlapping of labels & autopct in a matplotlib pie chart?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23577505/how-to-avoid-overlapping-of-labels-autopct-in-a-matplotlib-pie-chart)

but I have not been able to use the code in the answer in my case.

Can you please tell me what I should change in the code suggested in that answer?

Comment: use `loc='center right'` in `plt.legend(patches, labels, loc='center right', bbox_to_anchor=(-0.1, 1.),
           fontsize=8)`

Comment: Please add more details why it does not work for  you?

Comment: if you think that the other answer is what you want, then you just need to define the x, y and color in your case. try `s = df.groupby(Colour).size()` then `x = s.index`, `y = s.values`, `color = x`, then it should work?

Comment: @Ben. T. I am having some problem with `color = x` as I get `(red, None)`.

Comment: @Pygirl, I did not know what fields were x and y in my case.

Comment: what do you mean by you get `(red,None)`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Fine-tuning is easier to deal with in 'matplotlib'. I used the official reference as an example to modify your data. From [here](https://matplotlib.org/3.3.0/gallery/pie_and_polar_charts/pie_features.html#sphx-glr-gallery-pie-and-polar-charts-pie-features-py). The point is `explode=()`, which sets the number of slices to be cut out of a tuple.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

colours = ['red', 'orange', 'blue', 'white', 'green', 'yellow', 'brown']

labels = colours
sizes = df.groupby('Colour').size().tolist()
# only "explode" the 3nd,4th slice (i.e. 'Blue, White')
explode = (0, 0, 0.2, 0.2, 0, 0, 0)

fig1, ax1 = plt.subplots()
ax1.pie(sizes, explode=explode, labels=labels, autopct='%1.1f%%', shadow=True, startangle=90, colors=colours)

# Equal aspect ratio ensures that pie is drawn as a circle.
ax1.axis('equal')  

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @r-beginners. I am receiving this error: ValueError: 'explode' must be of length 'x'. Do you know how I could fix it?

Comment: The error may be that the number of elements in the pie chart is not the same as the number of elements of the `explode=()`.